# How to set up Windows Server 2003 to notify on scheduled task failure?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task

When trying to set up my Scheduled Task, I don't see an option to handle failures?  Is there functionality that I'm missing?

What I would like to have is an email notification when a scheduled task does not execute successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native way to do this in 2003.  This functionality appeared in 2008 onwards.  There are some 3rd party solutions, and you could script your own solution to parse through the Result of each scheduled task (using schtasks).

Comment: Or parse the event logs.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up a wmi subscription and consumer to the specific event in question to respond to failures.  See [Creating WMI Permanent Event Subscriptions Using MOF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/PermEvtSubscriptionMOF.aspx) for an example.  If your stuck on 2003 that's about your only option (other than 3rd party tools) however I'd strongly consider an upgrade before then.